# Como sacar el porcentaje en SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Las cantidades que manejo para realizar la consulta son:

```
(3427.2*100)/3716041.16 = 108427.9049953314659197012138188608776844
```

Como sacar hacer que arroje el porcentaje en enteros por que cómo sabra el sistema que el porcetaje es 108%

```
SELECT (SUM(COBRADO) * 100) / SUM(TOTAL)
FROM CL_RP_COBRANZA_TNR_TEORICO
WHERE TO_CHAR(FECHA_VENCIMIENTO,'MM/RRRR')='10/2015' AND
      ESTADO='HGO' AND
      SECCION='15'
ORDER BY ESTADO, SECCION, FECHA_VENCIMIENTO;
```

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: (3427.2*100)/3716041.16 = 0.0922271808205698

Comment: no entiendo tu comentario

Comment: Tu calculo esta mal

Comment: y como podria optener el pocentaje?

Comment: Ese es el porcentaje, 0.09%

Comment: si, pero podre hacer que el sistema sepa cual sera el porcetaje ya que el resultado de la consulta me lo arroja con cantidades mas grandes, me explico?

Comment: Como sacaste esos valores?

Comment: alli tienes , redondeas el valor y te da el digito que quieres `ROUND((SUM(COBRADO) * 100) / SUM(TOTAL) , 2)` puedes trambien truncarlo pero depende de lo que vas a mostrar

Comment: Acabo de descubrir que (3716041.16/3427.2)*100 = 108427.9049953315 Estas haciendo algo mal.

Answer (score 1):

Espero que te sirva si quieres algo mas solo detallalo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mysql

```
select CONCAT(FORMAT((sum(cobrado)*100)/sum(total),2),'%') as procentaje 
from cl_rp_cobranza_tnr_teorico where DATE_FORMAT(fecha_vencimiento,'%e/%Y')='10/2015'
and estado='hgo' and seccion='15' ORDER BY estado , seccion, fecha_vencimiento
```